# How to change the parameter value of href function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There is a function tool which have 2 parameters. I have to change the value of the parameter a(1 to 2) and b(2 to 3). How can I change this? Please give your valuable answer.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function tool(a,b) {
}   
</script> </head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:tool(1,2)" name ="link" title="before click">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is? Just change the value in the method call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the `href` property of the anchor node.

```js
function tool(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
}
document.getElementById('link').href='javascript:tool(2, 3);';
```

```html
<a href="javascript:tool(1, 2)" id="link" title="before click">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use what you want to do. But your question is not clear. As I understand I am giving your answer

**Answer 1**

```js
function tool(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
    document.getElementById('link').href='javascript:tool(2, 3);';
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:tool(1, 2)" id="link" title="before click">click here</a>
```

**Answer 2**

```js
function tool(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
    document.getElementById('link').href='javascript:tool('+(Number(a)+1)+', '+(Number(b)+1)+');';
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:tool(1, 2)" id="link" title="before click">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener:

```js
function tool(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener('click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    tool(2, 3);
  });
```

```html
<a href="javascript:tool(1,2)" name="link" id="link" title="before click">click here</a>
```